# core-date query (predicate) with aggregate Function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have a model with two Entities:

```
Master
  String name
  ....
  toMany Relationship to Detail

Detail
  Bool boolattr
  ....
  toOne Relationship to Master
```

As a result I want to get an Array of all Master-entities with the count of their corresponding Detail-entities with boolattr == YES  without fetching all the DEtail-Entities into Memory.
In SQL this would be possible with aggregate-functions in the databaselayer.
Is that possible in core-data too?

Thanks